# Spacy 3.0 Training custom NER --> Validation of this custom NER model

Tags: python-3.x, validation, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I trained a custom SpaCy Named entity recognition model to detect biased words in job description. Now that I trained 8 variantions (using different base model, training model, and pipeline setting), I want to evaluate which model is performing best.

But.. I can't find any documentation on the validation of these models.
There are some numbers of recall, f1-score and precision on the meta.json file, in the output folder, but that is no sufficient.

Anyone knows how to validate or can link me to the correct documentation? The documentation seem nowhere to be found.

NOTE: Talking about SpaCy V3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During training you should provide "evaluation data" that can be used for validation. This will be evaluated periodically during training and appropriate scores will be printed.

Note that there's a lot of different terminology in use, but in spaCy there's "training data" that you actually train on and "evaluation data" which is not training and just used for scoring during the training process. To evaluate on held-out test data you can use the cli [evaluate](https://spacy.io/api/cli#evaluate) command.

Take a look at [this fashion brands example project](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/ner_fashion_brands) to see how "eval" data is configured and used.

Comment: I saw the example projects on their github. But from that page you mentioned, I cannot tell how to run it during cli training. They have created commands for that specific project like: train, evaluate and package.

But for the evaluate command, they only tell that the input format should be the same as the train format.

Now that I am looking into SpaCy's documentation I might have found something that could help me out: https://spacy.io/api/cli#evaluate

Comment: Ah, right, that's the command you want for test data. I think the sample projects generally don't have held-out test data, so they don't show how to use it, but if you save your gold docs in a DocBin/.spacy file it should be fine.

Comment: The way I understand it, and tested as well is that you can run this command:
`python3 -m spacy evaluate output/model-best eval.spacy --output --displaycy-path`

By doing so, the eval.spacy is indicating a binary spacy file that is functioning as the hold-out dataset.

Comment: That's correct, I had forgotten about that command. I'll update my answer.